# Cuda5 and CMake

Tags: cuda, cmake

I have been working on getting some of the simple Cuda 5.0 samples to work on Windows 7 with CMake.  I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and Visual C++ Express 2010.

I had this working the other day and now it fails to compile, and I'm not quite sure why.  I generally do my coding in *nix environments so windows development environments aren't a strong area for me.

If anyone can help save me from pulling out more hair it'd be greatly appreciated.

The example is just the simple vectorAdd.cu file that comes with Cuda and a CMakeLists.txt file.  In the interest of keeping this posting short I'll hold off on putting the source file up since it's a little long.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

PROJECT( vectorAdd )

FIND_PACKAGE( CUDA REQUIRED )

CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} vectorAdd.cu )
```

When I try to compile, I get this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2/10/2013 6:24:59 PM.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "D:\Code\CPlusPlus\Cuda\example_1\Build\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.unsuccessfulbuild" because     "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>CustomBuild:
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/Code/CPlusPlus/Cuda/example_1/Build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07
2>------ Build started: Project: vectorAdd, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Build started 2/10/2013 6:24:59 PM.
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Creating "vectorAdd.dir\Debug\vectorAdd.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2>ComputeCustomBuildOutput:
2>  Creating directory "D:\Code\CPlusPlus\Cuda\example_1\Build\CMakeFiles\vectorAdd.dir\Debug\".
2>CustomBuild:
2>  Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir//Debug/vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.obj
2>nvcc : fatal error : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual Studio using 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/../../common7/Tools/vsvars32.bat'
2>  CMake Error at vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.obj.cmake:206 (message):
2>    Error generating
2>    D:/Code/CPlusPlus/Cuda/example_1/Build/CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir//Debug/vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.obj
2>  
2>  
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
2>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29
3>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Anyone have a suggestion?  I don't think I changed any settings from the time it worked to the time it stopped working.  I've tried rebooting and all that stuff.

Comment: Why are you using CMake on Windows? When you install CUDA 5, all the samples are pre-built.

Comment: Ultimately I was working on creating a framework to build on windows that used CMake.  I took one of the existing samples as a starting point to have something to compile.  The point isn't to run one of the existing examples, but to compile new code.